# Do any bits from the standard Mersenne Twister repeat more often than the total period?

Tags: random-number-generator

While the total period of MT19937 is $2^{19937}-1$ by design, is the period of the sequence of any of the individual bits from the output less than this? I'll admit I'm far too unfamiliar with group theory to understand Matsumoto and Nishimura's original proof for the period of the untruncated output, so I apologize if the answer follows trivially from it.

Comment: Each single one and zero bit repeats with about 50% chance *directly*. I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Fair point, edited.

Comment: are you talking about a part of the sequence or a sub-sequence

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a non-cryptographic random generator. It would be on-topic on [cs.se].

Comment: i think this is a fine question.

Comment: To make the question more interesting please edit the question to define mathematically  what "the period of the sequence of any of the individual bits" means. Say the whole sequence is $(s_i)_{0\leq i\leq N-1}.$ Do you mean something like $(s_i,s_{i+a},s_{i+b})_{0\leq i\leq N-1}$? You also speak of truncation which is different, maybe you want to let i vary over a shorter interval than $N$?